# Form not submit using jquery submit

Tags: jquery, confirm, jquery-confirm

I am using this code to check if the user select less checkbox than total checkbox and so to show jquery confirm if the user want to continue or not.
if the confirm popup appears because the user select less checkbox the form don't submit anything. What's the error?

JAVASCRIPT

```
var modulo = $("[type='checkbox']").length;
var count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;

if (count < modulo) {
    $.confirm({
        boxWidth: '30%',
        useBootstrap: false,
        title: 'Conferma',
        type: 'red',
        content: 'You have selected ' + count + ' objects of ' + modulo + '. Do you want to proceed?',
        buttons: {
            '
            confirm ': {
            text: 'Yes',
            btnClass: 'btn-info',
            action: function() {
                $("#veicoli").submit();
            }
        },
        'No': function() {}
    }
});

    return false;

} else {

    return true;

}
```

HTML

```
<form name="veicoli" id="veicoli" method="post" action="page.php" >
<input type="checkbox" name="rinnovo[44058]" value="renewal" />
<input type="checkbox" name="rinnovo[44059]" value="renewal" />
<input type="checkbox" name="rinnovo[44060]" value="renewal" />
<input type="checkbox" name="rinnovo[44061]" value="renewal" />
<button type="submit" name="compRinnovo" value="Prosegui" onClick="return verifica(this);">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can put a console.log in to verify that the "action" callback is definitely being run? And is "veicoli" definitely the id of your `<form>` tag? Does any console error occur when you press the Yes button?

Comment: Did you set breakpoint in confirm function? Is there call for submit works?
Please add html.

Comment: did you add jquery conform js?

Comment: @NedimHozić I updated my question with html, thank u

Comment: In you form there is not action attribute value. So, submit doesn't know which API must to call

Comment: closing `</form>` tag lost?

Comment: @NedimHozić I didn't write here but there is in the real code. The form work work correctly if the confirm popup don't need to appear. I think that the problem is here "action: function() {
                $("#veicoli").submit();
            }"

Comment: Did you try set breakpoint on action function? Is program goes there?

Comment: here it is, as described, working: https://jsfiddle.net/gjead5r2/ . You must have something else interfering with it. Check your browser console for errors, as I suggested earlier.

Comment: @ADyson yes, the code working fine...I resolved, was a problem with the destination page.